# Location of bluetooth audio files in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth, connection

Can some helpful soul explain the following:

- In 16.04, /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf does not seem to exist, does the
  information in this file exist elsewhere now?
- Is there a file that concerns tinkering with the HSP/HFP and A2DP
  profiles, and how i could have Ubuntu switch only to the latter?

Thanks in advance for any pointers

Answer (score 1):

I found this script somewhere from here. It uses pulseaudio commandline and disconnects bluetooth headphones and reconnects them using a2dp sink. Save it as .sh and `chmod +x filename.sh`  I used desktop shortcut to execute it.

```
pacmd set-card-profile `pacmd list-cards | grep bluez_card -B1 | grep index | awk '{print $2}'` off; sleep 2 ; echo -e "disconnect 50:C9:71:97:A1:86\n quit"|bluetoothctl;sleep 5; echo -e "connect 50:C9:71:97:A1:86\n quit"|bluetoothctl; sleep 5; pacmd set-card-profile `pacmd list-cards | grep bluez_card -B1 | grep index | awk '{print $2}'` a2dp_sink
```

You could play with `bluetoothctl` in terminal and try what you can do with it. Same thing with pulseaudio using command `pacmd`.